# Struts2 interceptor parametrs and its lifecycle

Tags: java, parameters, struts2, lifecycle, interceptor

we are using Struts2 in our code and I have scenario where I need to add custom parameter to the interceptor.
I have defined setter and getter in the interceptor

```
public Collection<Class<?>> getGroups();
public void setGroups(String groupsString);
```

I have interceptor defined in the stack:

```
<interceptor-ref name="beanValidatorInterceptor">
    <param name="excludeMethods">*</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

And I am setting additional parametres on action level

```
<action name="...">
  <interceptor-ref name="loginRequired">
    <param name="beanValidatorInterceptor.includeMethods">execute</param>
    <param name="beanValidatorInterceptor.groups">com.company.MyGroup</param>
  </interceptor-ref>
  <result>some.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I have one issue and one question

- Issue: groups parameters is not set (setGroups() is not called). Interceptor is called and the includeMethods are set.
- Question: do you happen to know what is interceptor lifecycle. Is it safe to set includeMethods and groups on the action level. In other words actions are sharing same  stack but need to pass different parameters

Comment: loginRequired is a stack which contains beanValidatorInterceptor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. Interceptors are like servlets--there is only one instance of an interceptor.*

Note, however, that with your current definition, *only* the "loginRequired" interceptor is defined on that action--*none* of the other framework interceptors will be run. If you declare an `<interceptor-ref>` on an action, you must define *all* the interceptors.

From the config it looks as though you're trying to define what group may access an action: that information should be stored in the *action*, not the interceptor, since it is the action that's being instrumented.

You have several options. You may use the "staticParams" interceptor to set the information on the action, you may define and implement an interface on the action and include a method that retrieves the permissions for that action, or use annotations on the action and interrogate the action and/or action method within the interceptor.

IMO the interceptor should be generic and not receive these types of parameters: you are adding action metadata to an interceptor. Instead, add the action metadata to the action, and use the interceptor to act on that metadata.

*Per interceptor-ref, actually; there can be multiple instances of an interceptor, but only when explicitly referenced in a stack declaration, and even then, there will be only one instance of the interceptor shared among requests that flow through that stack.

Comment: *So if I interceptor-ref a stack on every action is there stack instance per action. 2 actions, 2 instances of stack (each interceptor defined)

Comment: @szympans Correct. But I believe action-specific data should be in the action, not an interceptor, which also simplifies/lessens configuration.

Comment: Ok, I will consider your proposal. I like the way the MethodFilterInterceptor works... Thanks for your clarification

Comment: @szympans I'd consider either method-level annotations, or name-based method conventions, then. For methods, you could have a method called executeAccess that would define the access rights for the execute method, for example. The interceptor would see what method is being called, see if there's a corresponding access method, and call it if there is.